# Workflow Column renders 'undefined' with attr selector

Tags: 2013, workflow, spservices, splistitem, sharepoint-server

I'm using SPServices to get list items. I'm having difficulty getting the value for my workflow status column as it keeps coming back undefined.  I am using the internal name so not sure why it would come back undefined?  There are values in the column.  I know that SP stores the Workflow Status value as an integer.  Also, this is a Nintex Workflow not Designer if that makes a difference.  See code below:

```
$()SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='docLink' /></ViewFields>",
list name: "Program",
debug: true,
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
   $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr("ows_docLink0"));
});
}
});
```

Comment: Specify your Status column in viewfields to retrieve it's value

Comment: Hi @AkshayRandive.  Thank you so much for replying.  My status column is specified in ViewFields.. it is 'docLink'. Should I be specifying additional fields, such as an ID?

Comment: You can simply log response object in console and check what data you get

Comment: It just posts the document context...  checked the innerHTML node & i don't see the column listed at all...

Comment: To anyone else reading, the reason this isn't working is because SP 2013 uses a different Workflow Engine and the Workflow Status field is saved as a Hyperlink/URL value.  Currently searching to see how to query a Hyperlink field with SPServices for 2013 [though I suspect making a REST call is the easiest approach].